# Insert a Zero in a Pandas Dataframe pd.count() Result < 1

Tags: python, pandas, count, aggregate

I'm trying to find a method of inserting a zero into a pandas dataframe where the result of the .count()aggregate function is < 1. I've tried putting in a condition where it looks for null/None values and using a simple < 1 operator. So far I can only count instances where a categorical variable exists. Below is some example code to demonstrate my issue:

```
data = {'Person': ['Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob',], 'Result': ['Good', 'Good','Good','Good','Good','Good','Bad','Good','Bad','Bad',]}
dtf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

names = ['Jim','Bob']
append = []
for i in names:
    good = dtf[dtf['Person']==i]
    good = good[good['Result']=='Good']
    if good['Result'].count() > 0:
        good.insert(2,"Count",good['Result'].count())
    elif good['Result'].count() < 1:
        good.insert(2,"Count",0)

    bad = dtf[dtf['Person']==i]
    bad = bad[bad['Result']=='Bad']
    if bad['Result'].count() > 0:
        bad.insert(2,"Count",bad['Result'].count())
    elif bad['Result'].count() < 1:
        bad.insert(2,"Count",0)
    res = [good,bad]
    res = pd.concat(res)
    append.append(res)
    
    print(res)
```

The current output is:

```
  Person Result  Count
0    Jim   Good      5
1    Jim   Good      5
2    Jim   Good      5
3    Jim   Good      5
4    Jim   Good      5
  Person Result  Count
5    Bob   Good      2
7    Bob   Good      2
6    Bob    Bad      3
8    Bob    Bad      3
9    Bob    Bad      3
```

What I am trying to achieve is a zero count for Jim for the 'Bad' variable in the dtf['Results'] column. Like this:

```
  Person Result  Count
0    Jim   Good      5
1    Jim   Good      5
2    Jim   Good      5
3    Jim   Good      5
4    Jim   Good      5
5    Jim    Bad      0
  Person Result  Count
6    Bob   Good      2
7    Bob   Good      2
8    Bob    Bad      3
9    Bob    Bad      3
10   Bob    Bad      3
```

I hope this makes sense. Vive la Resistance! └[∵┌]└[ ∵ ]┘[┐∵]┘

Comment: What is the outcome you expect?

Comment: Oh... good question! I'll add it to the main question. Still learning the weirding ways of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you really need to keep all duplicate values?

Comment: Not necessarily, it was just an easy method of adding the count for each individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a multiindex `mi` from the product of `Person` and `Result` to keep missing combinations from `df`. Then count (`size`) all groups and reindex by the multiindex. Finally, merge the two dataframes use union of keys from both.

```py
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["Person"].unique(),
                                 df["Result"].unique()],
                                names=["Person", "Result"])

out = df.groupby(["Person", "Result"]) \
        .size() \
        .reindex(mi, fill_value=0) \
        .rename("Count") \
        .reset_index()

out = out.merge(df, on=["Person", "Result"], how="outer")
```

```py
>>> out
   Person Result  Count
0     Jim   Good      5
1     Jim   Good      5
2     Jim   Good      5
3     Jim   Good      5
4     Jim   Good      5
5     Jim    Bad      0
6     Bob   Good      2
7     Bob   Good      2
8     Bob    Bad      3
9     Bob    Bad      3
10    Bob    Bad      3
```

Output:

```py
names, append = list(zip(*out.groupby("Person")))
```

```py
>>> names
('Bob', 'Jim')

>>> append
(   Person Result  Count
 6     Bob   Good      2
 7     Bob   Good      2
 8     Bob    Bad      3
 9     Bob    Bad      3
 10    Bob    Bad      3,
   Person Result  Count
 0    Jim   Good      5
 1    Jim   Good      5
 2    Jim   Good      5
 3    Jim   Good      5
 4    Jim   Good      5
 5    Jim    Bad      0)
```

Comment: Everything is great! Thanks so much, your original output was perfect. I was actually just having trouble getting the dataframes to append in my example. I was able to apply your multi index solution to my original code, it's actually a much more eloquent solution :)

Comment: If you can't find a good solution to your next problem, feel free to open a new question? SO is here for that! Your current question is well formatted: an input, the code you tried and the wanted output. Keep in mind,  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)